# NodeJS first res.body object is in quotations

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have not found a solution to this problem anywhere online.

I am following a course online and creating a social media website using the MERN stack. I have run into an issue that is preventing me from registering users into this app.

The files are large in size and I will show some relevant code below

In Postman I make a POST request to the appropriate route (localhost:5000/api/users/register) and with all the appropriate keys needed (name: Coop , email: something@email.com, password: stoplookingatmypassword, password2: stoplookingatmypassword)

When I send the post request I am given this response

```
{
    "name": "Name field is required",
    "email": "Email field is required"
}
```

I added some console.logs to my code here to see what the issue was, as I have everything I need and the email field and name fields are there. Below is the beginning of my route.

```
router.post('/register',(req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body);

    const {errors, isValid } = validateRegisterInput(req.body);
    console.log(req.body);
    //Check Validation
    if(!isValid) {
        return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }
```

The first console.log gives me this output

```
{ 'name ': 'Coop',
  email: 'something@email.com',
  password: 'stoplookingatmypassword',
  password2: 'stoplookingatmypassword' }
```

The second console.log gives me this output

```
{ 'name ': 'Coop',
  email: 'something@email.com',
  password: 'stoplookingatmypassword',
  password2: 'stoplookingatmypassword',
  name: '' }
```

Obviously, this is a huge issue and after looking through my User schema and validation function I have no idea why the first name is in quotes, this issue is preventing me from going on and I couldn't find any solutions online. Anything helps here and any advice will go a long way, thanks for your time.

ISSUE:

```
'name ': 'Coop'
```

Here is the validateRegisterInput() function for reference

```
const Validator = require('validator');
const isEmpty = require('./is-empty');

module.exports = function validateRegisterInput(data) {
    let errors = {};

    data.name = !isEmpty(data.name) ? data.name : '';
    data.email = !isEmpty(data.email) ? data.email : '';
    data.password = !isEmpty(data.password) ? data.password : '';
    data.password2 = !isEmpty(data.password2) ? data.password2 : '';



    if(!Validator.isLength(data.name, { min: 2, max: 30})) {
        errors.name = 'Name must be between 2 and 30 characters';
    }

    if(Validator.isEmpty(data.name)) {
        errors.name = 'Name field is required';
    }

    if(!Validator.isEmpty(data.email)) {
        errors.email = 'Email field is required';
    }

    if(!Validator.isEmail(data.email)) {
        errors.email = 'Email is invalid';
    }

    if(Validator.isEmpty(data.password)) {
        errors.password = 'Password field is required';
    }

    if(!Validator.isLength(data.password, { min: 6, max: 30})) {
        errors.password = 'Password must be at least 6 charachters';
    }

    if(Validator.isEmpty(data.password2)) {
        errors.password2 = 'Confirm password field is required';
    }

    if(!Validator.equals(data.password, data.password2)) {
        errors.password2 = 'Passwords must match';
    }

    return {
        errors,
        isValid: isEmpty(errors)
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first property key in the request body is in quotes because the first property is `name` with a trailing space character at the end of the property name. Since this is a valid property name but not a valid variable name it escapes the property name with quotes.

Comment: My god had never noticed that, thank you for sharing this knowledge. I had to test to believe hahaha.

Comment: Wow, I just wasted like an hour and a half going through hell and back in my code just to figure that out. Thanks so much for your help it means the world to me.